# Clipboard API usage in Chrome not working as expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, clipboard, clipboarddata

I have a very strange behavior when I try to react on the `paste` event in Chrome in order to let the user paste multiple files from the file system into my web frontend.

This is the code of the function I register to the `paste` event:

```
let pasteFunction = function(event, callback) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!event.originalEvent && !event) {
        return;
    }

    let regardedEvent = (event.originalEvent || event)
    let items = regardedEvent.clipboardData.items;

    if(items === undefined){
        return;
    };

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(regardedEvent.clipboardData.files, function(file) {
        callback(file);
    });
}
```

Instead of iterating over the `files` property I also tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let content = items[i]
    if (content.kind !== 'file') continue;
    var blob = content.getAsFile();

    if (blob === null) {
        continue;
    }
    callback(blob);
}
```

There are multiple problems with this approach:

- The array *always* only contains *one* file, no matter how many I copy
- It does not work with files other than images
- The file name is not preserved (always `image.png`)

When I try in Safari, everything works like charm. Does it mean that Chrome's security policies disallow me to use the clipboard API as intended? Or is there something I can do about it?

MacOS Sierra (10.12.6) - Chrome 65.0.3325.181